# org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Item getName

Tags: api, exception, jenkins, groovy, archive

I was trying to delete the old history of builds using a groovy script, and earlier it was working fine and without any changes now I am facing issue as below:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Item getName
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:175)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:137)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedCall.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
at Script1.deleteBuildHistory(Script1.groovy:71)
at Script1$deleteBuildHistory.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedCall.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:58)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.run(GroovySandbox.java:141)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:333)
at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.run(SystemGroovy.java:95)
at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:59)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1798)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Execute system Groovy script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

In my groovy I am using the API "hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(envVar.get("JOB_NAME"));" to get the Jenkins job name. Since it is working earlier, now I am facing this issue and not sure how to resolve the same. Kindly provide inputs.

Comment: Just my recommendation for future: use [Discard Old Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin). It let's you specify how many builds do you want to keep in history.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a rather generic way to access data from an object, which might be exploited somehow, so it got blacklisted or rather not whitelisted in Jenkins Groovy Sandbox.

You have several options here:

1. Just add an exception using [in-process script approval](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/)
2. Use a less generic and therefore saver syntax like `env.JOB_NAME`.

I would definitely go for the second option in your case for it has no disadvantages and is simpler then your current code.

As for why it worked before: three might have been an approval, which somehow got lost –happened to me once– or the call you are using got un-whitelisted in an update of the security plugin.

Comment: You mean to get job name by mentioning as "hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(envVar.get("env.JOB_NAME"))" ??

Comment: @Dinesh yes. I assumed that you wrote that in your Jenkinsfile.

Comment: @ Michael  I have provided env.JOB_NAME like this:
def buildJob = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(envVar.get("env.JOB_NAME"));
def buildProject = buildJob.asProject();

 But I am facing the below issue:

Comment: ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method asProject() on null object
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)

Comment: @Dinesh that's a very different issue as the one in your question. Also it is not clear from your question what are you trying to achieve. Please provide more information and stick to one problem.

Comment: I wanted to delete build history in my Jenkins job since with so many jobs it occupies so much memory, so wanted to delete the history. For that I use groovy script, and in that I am facing such issue.

Comment: @Dinesh how about option 1 from my answer then?

Comment: That thing I am checking how to add an exception. I will check and will get back to you.